# Stuck in wireframe

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, 3d-view, wireframe

[image]

Using blender for the first time, and was just messing around with buttons, I think I clicked one of the physics simulation buttons, and now I'm stuck in this wireframe view. I don't want to make this geometry again (I've given up multiple times) Help?

Comment: Nvm, realised that the texture was removed, so it defaulted to wireframe

Answer (score 1):

go to object properties - > viewport visibility -> change from wire to solid or texured

[image]